# not loading GSAP animation in production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gatsby, firebase-hosting, gsap

The very simple GSAP animation made with a gatsby plugin of Green sock animation loads an Iframe through react and makes it fade in and out.

When I deploy on my firebase app the animation no longer works.

What possible reason could stop the animation from running when in deployment when it works perfectly when done locally?

There are no problems reported in the console. And I have no idea how to properly use event breakpoints in react.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TimelineLite, CSSPlugin } from "gsap/all";
import Iframe from 'react-iframe';
import F from "../land.module.scss";

import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.jsx";

thing component extension etc {

constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // container
    this.commentContainer = null;
    // tween
    this.Comments = null;
}

componentDidMount(){
// create tween


    this.Comments = new TimelineLite({ paused:true })

    // .to(this.commentContainer, 2, { x: 300 })
    // .to(this.commentContainer, 1, { rotation: 360, transformOrigin: "center" })
    .fromTo(this.commentContainer, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, duration: 1});
    }


render()
return

<>
<button onClick={() => this.Comments.play()}>just the button</button>



    <div className={`${F.fb} col-12 mt-3`} ref={ this_ => this.commentContainer = this_ }>

<Iframe> ---- the iframe details etc URL, position, width height styles. 


export defaults.
```

The code may not help stall as it works correctly in every way when using gatsby develop.

Comment: You might want to check the network panel of your browser too, as I suspect that one of the files your animation needs is not included in the deployed web app.

Comment: You should use GSAP 3's formatting. i.e. `new TimelineLite({ paused:true })` should be `gsap.timeline({ paused:true })`. Then import GSAP via `import { gsap } from "gsap";`

Comment: there is no file. it is a disc holding an Iframe being changed, and it works in development so I assume the formating does not matter or it would not have that discrepancy?